# Linhas da Listview desaparecem ao fazer scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, rolamento

Estou a usar uma `listview` e a populá-la com um `cursoradapter`. Ao fazer scroll para cima e para baixo as linhas desaparecem. Se começo com 30 elementos, à medida que faço scroll para cima e para baixo vou ficando com menos... até ficar com mais ou menos o numero de linhas sem ser preciso fazer scroll.

O meu adapter é o seguinte:

```
public class AdapterChatDetail extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private Cursor mCursor;


    public AdapterChatDetail(Context context, Cursor c)
    {
        super(context, c, 0);
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,  Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.linha_chatdetail, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View mView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
             ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.msg1)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contrato.Chat.COLUMN_MSG)));

        }
    }
```

E a lista está definida desta forma

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroll"
        android:layout_above="@id/linha2"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Alguma ideia do que poderá estar a passar-se?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Desativa o cache do scroll no seu XML da lista para ver se `

```
 <ListView
        android:scrollingCache="false"`         
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroll"
        android:layout_above="@id/linha2"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```